# How do you propagate a click to child elements if the parent element has preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE**:
this doesn't work in the latest version of firefox (15.0.1):
http://jsfiddle.net/DerNalia/NdrNV/5/

clicking the checkbox navigates to google... but it shouldn't :(

it appears that adding e.stopPropagation() doesn't help / doesn't work.

---

playarea: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNalia/NdrNV/1/

What I'm trying to do:
When I click the checkbox that is next to (but actually is a child element of) the anchor, it should change states, and also change the state of the "other" checkbox.

But because the anchor has e.preventDefault() invoked, the checkbox never gets checked.

Here is my markup

```
<a href="#">Link Name <input class="home" type="checkbox"/></a>
<br />
Sync'd checkbox: <input class="other" type="checkbox" />​
```

Here is some the troubled jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("input.home").click(function() {
        $("input.other").click();
    });

    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // prevent default so we can do some ajaxy things instead of follow the href
    });
})​
```

So, how do I change the jQuery click action on the anchor tag such that clicks propagate to child elements (but I can still do ajaxy things without the browser following the href of the anchor tag)?

Is there a way to do this without changing the markup? (the way it is now makes semantic sense for my web application)

Comment: Clicks (in fact, all events) propagate **up** the DOM, not down, so there's no concept of clicks propagating to child elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `event.preventDefault` would cancel the event.

Using e.preventDefault on click on the `checkbox` which is wrapped inside `<a>` would not let you change the checkbox state.

A workaround I could think of is to set the checkbox state in a different context so that the `e.preventDefault` code is ineffective.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NdrNV/10/

```
$(function() {
    $("input.home").click(function() {
        $("input.other").click();
    });

    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var setCheckbox = function() {
            var checkbox = $(e.target)[0];
            checkbox.checked = checkbox.checked?false:true;
        }

        if ($(e.target).is(':checkbox')) {
            setTimeout(setCheckbox, 0);
        }

    });
})
```

***Note:** This is a workaround.*

Comment: @TheLindyHop Do you mean it worked for you? or you still having issues.

Comment: yup. it worked. thanks! exactly what I wanted, juts couldn't award bounty at the time =p

Answer (score 1):

You can put condition e.target.tagName like this,

```
 if(e.target.tagName == 'A')        
       e.preventDefault();
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/NdrNV/3/)**

```
$(function() {
    $("input.home").click(function() {
        $("input.other").click();
    });

    $("a").click(function(e) {
        if(e.target.tagName == 'A')        
           e.preventDefault();      


        // prevent default so we can do some ajaxy things instead of follow the href
    });
})​
```

Comment: this doesn't work in firefox :( http://jsfiddle.net/DerNalia/NdrNV/5/

It ends up navigating to google (the url in the href)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
        $("input.home").click(function() {
            if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked')
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
            else                               
                $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
            $("input.other").click();
        });

    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // prevent default so we can do some ajaxy things instead of follow the href

        var target = e.target; // object that triggers the event
        $(target).children().trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can just do `$(target).children().trigger('click');` - the `.trigger()` function acts on all elements in the jQuery object, so the `.each()` is unnecessary.

Comment: I stand corrected. I wasn't sure if that was the case so instead of checking I wrote code that I was sure will be valid.

Comment: this actually doesn't work, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNalia/NdrNV/4/ =\

Comment: Well that would be because the actual element clicked does not have *any* children. Your `input` has no children it's an inline terminated tag.

Comment: There are actually 2 problems - one I fixed above adding the checkbox-toggle behaviour. The other one I explained above and you'll have to fix it.